# Communities: Provisioning existing Salesforce licensed users as Partner Users

Tags: community, partner-communities, role-hierarchy, provisioning

**Existing Solution:**
Dealers and Vendors (external users) using Salesforce Licenses.
They are assigned to Roles (Dealers at the bottom below Vendors).
They own Accounts, Opportunities and other custom Object Records.

**Proposed Solution:**
To make external Users (Dealers & Vendors) as Partner Users via Communities.

**Observation:**
As per the documentation the provisioning is little tricky.

It requires creation of a Partner Account (this Account Owner's Role becomes important as it becomes logically above the Role Salesforce creates automatically while promoting a Contact into a Partner User).
Partner Users to be created as Contacts under the Partner Account.
Contacts under the Partner Account to be promoted as Partner Users.
Salesforce automatically creates a new Role and assigns the same to the newly promoted Partner User.

**Problem:**
How do we provision Partner Users from existing Salesforce Users.
How do they fit-in into the existing Role hierarchy. Currently these Users own Accounts, Opportunities,
Contacts and other Custom Object Records.
Vendors are above Dealers in the Role hierarchy. How do we maintain the same hierarchy once transitioning the Salesforce Users into Partner Users.
How does the Record ownership affect. While promoting Contacts into Partner Users a New User and a New Role is created.

Suggestions and advise from the community will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the license type that you are using for your community User.

If its partner community license then roles and sharing will be applied and you can assign roles as per your role hierarchy .

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

If you take high volume portal license you may need to reply on sharing sets for sharing records .

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_sharing_set.htm&language=en_US

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf
Pls refer section "Creating Communities Users" ... in a nutshell Partner User Role is automatically created and assigned...it is logically subordinate to the Role of the Partner Account owner Role ... the automatically created Role is not available for selection in Organization hierarchy ...

Comment: @sKaLiDhAsAn I guess then only alternative is to use sharing sets if this role is not available in hierarchy .Sharing sets should help you to share the records for community Users